# Neck circles during warm up / neck circles during dancing, healthy, unhealthy, proof?

Tags: health, health-risk, warm-up, neck

I was reading here:

https://sequencewiz.org/2014/03/11/neck-circles-can-compress-cervical-nerves-cause-issues/

I remember well that I was educated as well in high school, to not do neck circles. My sports teacher told me "neck circles backwards (i.e. into the neck) are no longer to be used".

In latin america? everyone is doing neck circles during warm up. When I mention it's bad practice they go like "LOL we all have to die anyway" and keep doing it.

I tried to look up spanish articles about it, found *nothing*. I found some german and english articles like the one above, but nothing scientific. Is there scientific evidence?

the german article, actually stated that 2 people died in the 80s
source (is german):
http://sport-attack.net/ueber-kopfkreisen-und-schulterkreisen-vorwaerts-ungesunde-uebungen/?print=pdf

I translate the bit where they mention people died:

> If the blood supply is interrupted here, may cause dizziness or, in extreme cases, cycloidal collapse. Especially in the In the 80s, there were even two deaths in competitive sports that made the headlines, causing many exercise dictionaries were rewritten.

so, where is that scientific proof? like a solid article.

Or is it all a myth, and that's why there is no proof? "Go neck circles go!" ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you in your search for research studies, but I can explain why your instructor wants to do head circles.  Head circles are a sexy accent in stripping choreography.  As an example, in this famous [strip scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Y_QIYMzgfM), there is a quick head circle at 1:35 s and another one at 1:44 s.   The truth is that Aerobics and Zumba instructors practice head circles because they are unconsciously emulating strippers they have seen in movies.  This is why head circles will always be around.

Although head circles may be sexy, this doesn't make them healthy.  As an aging adult, there is no reason to do head circles.  If you want to stretch your neck, then stretch one direction of movement at a time, go slowly and mindfully, don't use momentum, and return to neutral after each stretch.   And for Goodness sake, don't pull on your head.  I see people pulling on their head all the time at the gym.  There is no reason to pull on your head when you are stretching your neck.  If you know what you are doing, then you can get all the stretch you want with gravity alone.

Good luck in your exercise journey, because you will encounter lots of stupidity like head circles.

ps. [Here](https://www.bloomsbury-osteopathy.co.uk/cspm11-first-rib-and-trapezius-stretching-exercise/) is a stretch for the neck I like.  They say it is for the Trapezius, but it is also stretching muscles in your neck.

Answer (score 1):

Your instructors are correct that neck circles or head rolling are not healthy for the neck.  Circles require multiple, coordinated movements of the spine.  The small facet joints can be compromised as the weight of the head manages the complicated motion, especially as the head goes into side bending and back into extension. These small joints are not designed to handle this type of load.

Here is a brief article describing the danger of neck circles. https://www.familychiropractic.com/single-post/2016/02/15/Protect-Your-Neck-The-Danger-of-Neck-Circles